# Why is the dictionary element returning 1 as far as length when the String at that location should return 9?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, comparison, string-comparison

So I am trying to make something that subtracts a certain amount from a string to make the 2 strings equal in length the problem is when I try to find the length of the element 1 which is stored as 0000 0000 it returns 1. Also, the code is grabbing from a file but the only relevant element is 1. Here is the code in question:

```
import re

insSpec2 = {}
z = 0
bool(z)
TestString = "0100 0001"

while z == 0:
    f = open("Specifier", 'r')

    for word in f:
        i = 0
        insSpec2[i] = re.split('r|a', word)
        print(insSpec2[i])

        insLength = len(insSpec2[i])
        testLength = len(TestString)
        if testLength > insLength:
            diff = testLength-insLength
        else:
            diff = insLength-testLength

        print(insLength)#returns 1
        print(testLength, insLength) #returns 9 1
        print(diff)#returns 8
        print(insSpec2[0].__len__()) #returns 1

        if insLength < testLength:
            changeVar = 8 - insLength
            while TestString != insSpec2:
                #print(testLength)
                newStr = TestString[:-diff]
                #print(newStr)
        elif insSpec2[i] == TestString:
            print("Found Match", insSpec2[i])
            z = 1
            break

        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `re.split` returns a list not a string, insSpec[i] = ['0000 0000']. It has length 1

Comment: So how can I get it to get the string length?

Comment: insSpec[i] contains results of regexp split. So if the string actually has not been split, the string length is `len(insSpec[i][0])`. If it has than this expression returns the length of the first substring.